# How can I pass array of pointers between my functions in C?

Tags: c, oracle-pro-c

I am biginner in C and PRO*C and need some help. I have a structure as below:

```
  typedef struct pt_st{
   char (*s_no)[100];
   char (*s)[100];
    } pt_st;
```

I have a function like c_info which calls post function:

```
int c_info(pt_st ir_st)
{
int   li_result = 0;
li_result = post(ir_st.s_no)
}
```

and post function is :

```
int post(char *is_st)
{
//do something
}
```

When I compile my program , I get three errors:

```
warning: passing arguments post from incompatible pointer type
warning: passing arguments post make integer from ponter without cast
warning: passing arguments post make ponter from integer without cast
```

Does anyone kow how can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: To declare a array of `char` do `char arr[42]`. Doing as you do (`char (*parr)[42]`) declares a pointer (`parr`) to an array of 42 `chars`.

Comment: Note: I retagged, cause I think the OP means the Oracle thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pt_st.s_no` as well a `pt_st.s` both declare a pointer to an array of `char`.

So the function `post()` needs to expect such, like:

```
int post(char (*s_no)[100]);
```

If the shown definition of `int post(char * is_st)` cannot be changed, then call it like this:

```
pt_st s = ... /* some initialisation */

int result = post(*(s.s_no));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but still i get the same warning.

Comment: @Dax: Which warning? Your question mentions 3 different warnings? And also for which of my both proposals?

Comment: I still get all these three warnings : warning: passing arguments post from incompatible pointer type
warning: passing arguments post make integer from ponter without case
warning: passing arguments post make ponter from integer without case             for yur first proposal i.s. int post(char (*s_no)[NULL_BIG_SEQ_NO]);

Comment: @Dax: Sry, but are you sure you are editing/compiling the right files? Also the error messages you quote are not 100% what any compiler would issue: "*ponter*"? "*case*"?

Comment: Also check which lines the compilers tells you for where the warnings occur.

Comment: at this line:   li_result = post(ir_st.s_no)

Comment: @Dax: The type of `post()`'s parameter needs to be the same as the type of the variable you pass into: `char (*)[100]` or written as a full variable definition: `char (*s_no)[100]`

Comment: I call post function like post(ir_st.s_no), and ir_st.s_no is char (*s_no)[100]. Is something wrong? Sorry to ask simple questions!

Comment: @Dax: And `post()` is `int post(char (*s_no)[100]);`? For protoype **and** implementation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78699/discussion-between-dax-and-alk).